# How to properly use SwipeableDrawer inside a Modal in MUI (Material-UI)?

Tags: material-ui

Code sample / demo can be checked [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simpledialog-demo-material-ui-forked-rtiitz?file=/src/components/SimpleDialog.jsx).

As title says, I want to use a SwipeableDrawer inside of a Modal in Material UI.
The problem is that Modal by default uses `position: fixed` for positioning Backdrop component, Modal container etc.
The way `position: fixed` works is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).
I have fixed the positioning issue with `transform: translateY(0)`.

Now, when I toggle the SwipeableDrawer I get for a few moments an overflow (scroll).
I can ugly fix that scroll by adding `overflowY: hidden` - which I don't like but for the sake of the argument.

But right now I still have the basic problem, but it's not ugly anymore. As you can see in the [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69d14.jpg) the content shakes from the moment the transition starts till the moment the transition ends.

Ideally I would like to have the same result as using a SwipeableDrawer outside of a modal.

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog` extends `Modal` but has other special properties such as text overflow. [Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/):

> A Dialog is a type of modal window that appears in front of app
> content to provide critical information or ask for a decision. Dialogs
> disable all app functionality when they appear, and remain on screen
> until confirmed, dismissed, or a required action has been taken.
>
> Dialogs are purposefully interruptive, so they should be used
> sparingly.

So firstly I would use a `Modal` to see if that reduces your challenge. Secondly, I would create a parent component housing your swipe-able drawer, *then* pass that parent component into your `Modal`. Something to this effect:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => 
  <Container>
    //your drawer goes in here
  </Container>

 const App = () => <Container>
  <Modal 
   //modal props
  >
    <ParentComponent/>
  </Modal>
 </Container>
```

Hope thats helpful.